# Angular ngIf animation fails

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I am trying to animate an `*ngIf` statement, but I can't seem to get it to first remove the element and then enter the other element.

Here is what my code currently does:

[image: Example of what happens]

This is the code I currently have (excluding the form):

Typescript:

```ts
trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition('* => *', [
        query(':leave', [
          useAnimation(fadeOutDown)
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          useAnimation(fadeInUp)
        ]),
      ])
    ])
```

HTML:

```html
<div [@fadeInOut]="states.twoFactorRequired">
    <div *ngIf="!states.twoFactorRequired">
        <!-- Form 1 -->
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="states.twoFactorRequired">
        <!-- Form 2 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

- Use `[hidden]` property
- Put the animation on the `div` element
- Use transition states `* => void` and `void => *`
- Use `ngSwitch`

Note that the div does not have any additional styling, and the animations `fadeOutDown` & `fadeInUp` are from [ng-animate](https://github.com/jiayihu/ng-animate)

Comment: Could you add your `fadeOutDown` and `fadeInUp` properties?

Comment: @Edric I did not make the source code, it is from the library [ng-animate](https://github.com/jiayihu/ng-animate)